# Asynctask: Two values to AsyncTask and process in doInBackground

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to store values to my DB and I am using AsyncTask to do this process. I am pulling data from the webserver and storing them DB by sending Json array to async and then extracting the value and storing them.  I am setting this up in for Loop.

Now these records sometimes have sub records. To identify sub records in my localDB. I am adding another field called parentID so I am trying to send parentID along with jsonarray to AsyncTask. I am not sure how to do so?

Here is what I have done till now:

```
private void getSubRecords(String recordID2)
    {
        final String parent_ID = recordID2;
        final RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
        requestParams.put("RecId", recordID2);

        final String urlforsubrec = getResources().getString(R.string.subreclink);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(urlforsubrec , requestParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    success = response.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == Integer.parseInt(getResources().getString(R.string.successvalue))) {
                    details = response.getJSONArray(TAG_DETAIL);
                    new AddSubRecordAsyncTask().execute(details); //Need to send parentID String
```

**I want to send parent_ID along with details(JsonArray)? how do I do that to reflect in AsyncTask?**

```
        } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                Log.e("Error","Check internet");                  }
     });
    }
```

Here is the asyncTask (Not sure what to change to hear to reflect both JsonArray and String.

```
    private class AddSubRecAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, Void, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(JSONArray... params)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < params[0].length(); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);

                    riD = c.getString(TAG_RID);
                    rnAme = c.getString(TAG_RNAME);
                    rcHild = c.getString(TAG_RCHILD);


                    localDB.setSubRecDetails(riD, rnAme, rcHild, rcAtegory, parent_ID);

                    if (rcHild.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.subvalue))) {
                        getSubRecords(riD);
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String object)
        {
            Log.e("All", "Done");
        }
       }
    }
```

I want to send JsonArray ( in my above code "details") and String value (parent_ID) as it is final value..

Not sure how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AsyncTasks` are objects, so you can always sneak some extra data in with a constructor.

```
private class AddSubRecAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, Void, String> {
    final String mId;
    public AddSubRecAsyncTask(String id) {
       mId = id;
    }
    ...
```

Then you are free to use `mId` in your `doInBackground` method.  Invoke like,

new AddSubRecAsyncTask(parent_ID).execute(details);

Another common approach is to create your `AsyncTask` as an anonymous object in the place you need it instead of a named class.  Then it has access to all member variables of the contain class and final fields in the containing method.  Less chance for reuse with that approach, but useful in some situations.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I will tried your above code. project ran successfully until saving to db. I am getting the following error when saving to database. I have it in For loop.  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.

Comment: That is a separate issue.  Are you closing the database in the loop?  If so, don't.

Comment: I am not closing the database in the loop. I am having SQLiteOpenHelper and I am calling that... It closes everytime after writing.

Comment: That is likely causing problems.  Don't call it until you are completely done with the database

Comment: actually this causing only after putting in the async. I tried to save the records in the main theard in the loop. I didn't get this error at all.

Comment: Guess what even after I removed db.close(); I am getting connection closed issue.

Comment: Not sure.  It might have something to do with the DB being access on multiple threads.

Comment: No worries Let me check it. Thanks Anyways!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way I used before, maybe not the best one.

You can create a class to include all the informaiton you want to send to the AsyncTask, like below :

```
class ProcessTicket {

public final String parentId;

public final JSONArray data;

}
```

then the AsyncTask can be written as:

```
private class AddSubRecAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ProcessTicket, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(ProcessTicket... params){
    ...
    }
}
```

Then you can extact the parameters you want in the doInBackground function.